# compere string to string after removing string characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, html-helper

i have a string that i use as url parameter s query and i need to get all the data that is relevant in order to get a "clean Url" i have remove all characters with helper but i cant compere it to my Db string Update With the code now it's 0 results  `

View:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","schools",
    new { @venue =Html.ResolveSubjectForUrl( gig.Venue)})">@gig.Venue
</a>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string venue)
{
    var testq = _context.LectureGigs.Where(v => v.Venue.StartsWith(venue));
    /just made the query shorter for clear code 
}

public static class UrlExtensions
{
    public static string ResolveSubjectForUrl(this HtmlHelper source, string subject)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(subject, "[^\\w]", ""), "[-]{2,}", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you have?

Comment: @DavidG yes i should have say that, im getting 0 results

Comment: Could you post an example value of `subject`?

Comment: @Dillanm for example" new york museum" To "newyorkmuseum "

Comment: You now have the problem that if you source data contains "new york museum" and "newyork museum", that you cannot tell them apart.

Comment: @DavidG im not sure i understand your comment

Comment: If your `LectureGigs.Venue` has a row with `new york museum` and another with `newyork museum`, your Regex makes them look equivalent. That's just an example (possibly a bad one) to show why your technique might be a bad idea.

Comment: @DavidG you do have an interesting point , but for now i think all names  are unique

Comment: "it works for now" - I would count that phrase as one of the most dangerous in programming...

Comment: @DavidG i agree , as we speak now i'm trying to think how to generate a unique key for each venue , i'' probably add street to the usl , but ist steel will not match the query

Comment: Well you can use your method above, but you really should store that value (we usually call it a "slug") back into your database and give that column a unique constraint. That way when you generate another one that clashes, you can add "2" to the end for example to make it unique. alternatively give each row a GUID which is essentially the same thing.

Comment: @DavidG you're welcome to add to my attempt to explain this as an answer!

Comment: @DavidG above where ? do you mean i should write something to run on my db & add the "slug" vlue  too each venue ?

Comment: @DavidG if i understand , i should post a new Q asking how to run on my table and copy each venue to a new slug table ?

Comment: Actually, you should just figure that out yourself, it's not hard to do.

Comment: @DavidG true -:) but, what i dont know is how to create the slug to run there

Comment: @DavidG thanks for your help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this would be to store your 'Resolved' string in the database as part of the  `venue`.

For example:

```
class Venue
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
}
```

If you store this in a table that is something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Venue
(
    [Name] nvarchar(512) NOT NULL,
    [Slug] nvarchar(512) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)
```

Then finding the gigs for that venue becomes as simple as:

```
_context.LectureGigs.Where(v => v.Venue.Slug.StartsWith(slug));
```

Obviously, when you save your `Venue` you need to populate the Slug value with the value from `ResolveSubjectForUrl` (which you can use as `string` extension or a `static` method without the `HtmlHelper` parameter)

Comment: So why not query against that data, rather than the `Venue`?

Comment: i need to get all related data aginst the venue while this venue has no id/key

Comment: @AssafOur I've added to my answer to help explain this

Comment: thats great now the only Q is, do i need to  i run on my OLD db data and add slug  to each venue ?

Comment: @DavidKemp A little surprised that with 6.5k rep that you don't know how to format your code yet...

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be searching for `Slug.StartsWith(...)`, it should match exactly.

Comment: @DavidKemp if i understand , i should post a new Q  asking how to run on my table and copy each venue to a new slug table ?

Comment: @DavidG - sorry, being lazy </mea-cupla>

Comment: @AssafOur - I think you already have all the pieces to do this.

Comment: @DavidKemp Pressing Ctrl+K is lazier than typing 4 backticks twice! (PS Markdown only requires 3 backticks but SO doesn't support that method)